# CSS hover issues only in opera

Tags: css, opera

I have the [site](http://webofdreams.ro)
 and it renders ok, even in IE. However in Opera 11.62 there is a very weird bug whenever I am hovering over the links from the navbar. Why does this happen? It is very annoying.
There is also a very weird thing that is happening, if I resize the browser window so the last link is out the pages than only the last link it displays ok on hover, but the other 2 are still broken.

Comment: have you tried with `min-height: 100%;` on the `a:hover`?

Comment: I see from your css that you set the `<ul>` as `inline-block`. Have you tried removing it? I had the very same issue, with the only difference that i declared it as an `inline` element and wasn't able to see the hover on the contained elements. I know it's a bit late for an answer (and your site works well anyways), but i thought i should share my solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line of code to `a:hover`

```
height: 100%;
```

So you get:

```
a:hover { 
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #93C9ED 0px, #76B4E1 100%) transparent;
  border-bottom: medium none currentColor;
  border-left: 1px solid #1C5E9C;
  border-right: 1px solid #1C5E9C;
  border-top: 1px solid #1C5E9C;
  color: #275D8B;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, the problem stays the same. I have also tried to add line-height:2.5em which is the line-height of a, and it does not do anything and if the line-height or height is more than 2.5em it moves the content up a few pixels.

Comment: Well, I tried it as well (Dev tools) and it works ... Strange.

Comment: I have added the line on the server and both my home computers show the same bug.

Comment: i have cleared the cache on the client side. I have no control over the server cache.

Answer (score 1):

Add a height to the anchor tag, same as your line-height:

```
header nav ul li a { height:2.5em; }
```

This works for me, in Opera 11.64. I see you've already tried this solution, but I'm guessing the reason you haven't made it work, is because the line-height is 2.5em, not 2.8 (unless you've changed it).

Comment: tried both solutions suggested to no avail befor posting, sorry to not mention that

Comment: Have you tried setting a fixed pixel value? I believe Opera had issues with this in earlier versions (pre v10), but thought it had been fixed. It's worth a shot anyhow.

Comment: you are right the problem is in the em, however if I set it at 30px it has the same problem and if I move it to 31px it resizes the whole nav bar.

Comment: yes you are right about my mistake with line height, but I tried both dimensions